How to Select n Nodes in a Disconnected Graph to Maximize Neighbor Coverage?
I have a problem from graph theory for which I cannot find a solution in the literature: an undirected, disconnected graph is given. Now n vertices must be selected and then these vertices and their immediate neighbors are colored. The task is to select the vertices in such a way that as many vertices as possible are colored.
The graphic illustrates the problem for a graph and three vertices (A, B and C), which were ideally chosen here (note that choosing D would be an error).
Does anyone know an algorithm for this problem? Could a greedy approach be successful, or is the problem perhaps NP-complete?


Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

tl;dr: There is no efficient algorithm (assuming P!=NP).
independet sets
What you have here is the independent set problem, with the added constraint that you want an independent set of size k to have maximal coverage. Finding any maximal independent set (without your coverage constraint) is in P. In fact it's pretty straightforward, because maximal only means that it cannot be further extended. However, finding the maximUM independent set is NP-complete.
cliques
Now, you don't care about it being maximum but being of exactly size k. This is where cliques come into play. Because each independent set is a clique in the graph's complement graph (edges and non-edges swapped). So, finding either a clique or an independent set of size k is NP-complete. In fact it's one of the NP-complete problems.
Your problem
So, assuming you could solve your problem in P-time, you would have a P-time algorithm for finding k-size independent sets (albeit with the added difficulty that you want them to have maximal coverage). So you can reduce both k-clique and k-independent set to your problem in P-time (and P-space) as well as transform it back. So you would have a P-time algorithm for k-clique and k-independent set. Which contradicts their NP-completeness.
vertex cover?
This problem is not really related to vertex cover.
Greedy?
A greedy algorithm will also not semi-decide this, because high-degree nodes are not necessarily part of the optimal solution, not even part of a good solution.
Greedy Example
Imagine an (s+2)-degree star with each end-point having an s-degree star attached to it. So you have one vertex "a" with degree (s+2), (s+2) vertices "b" with degree (s+1), and finally (s+2)*s vertices "c" with degree 1.
Here is an example for s=4.

If you now query with k=s+2, the greedy algorithm will have to select vertex "a" first but now cannot select any of the "b" vertices. It will have to spend k-1=s+1 selections on the low-degree "c" vertices resulting in a total coverage of 1+(s+2)+(k-1)=2s+4.
However, the optimal solution for k=s+2 is to select all the "b" vertices, which covers all vertices in the graph, namely: 1+(s+2)+(s+2)*s = s2+3s+3.
Same graph coloured with greedy (red) and optimal (blue):

So: the greedy algorithm can produce arbitrarily bad solutions.
However, greedy might give you a starting point from which you can possibly derive a better (if not necessarily optimal) solution with something akin to augmenting paths.

Here's the graphviz code for the figures:
graph {
  a[color="red"];
  c11[color="red"];
  c12[color="red"];
  c13[color="red"];
  c14[color="red"];
  c21[color="red"];

  b1[color="blue"];
  b2[color="blue"];
  b3[color="blue"];
  b4[color="blue"];
  b5[color="blue"];
  b6[color="blue"];

  a -- b1;
  a -- b2;
  a -- b3;
  a -- b4;
  a -- b5;
  a -- b6;

  b1 -- c11;
  b1 -- c12;
  b1 -- c13;
  b1 -- c14;

  b2 -- c21;
  b2 -- c22;
  b2 -- c23;
  b2 -- c24;

  b3 -- c31;
  b3 -- c32;
  b3 -- c33;
  b3 -- c34;

  b4 -- c41;
  b4 -- c42;
  b4 -- c43;
  b4 -- c44;

  b5 -- c51;
  b5 -- c52;
  b5 -- c53;
  b5 -- c54;

  b6 -- c61;
  b6 -- c62;
  b6 -- c63;
  b6 -- c64;
}

